# Android Raw Query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to implement a function that uses a raw query but am running into some trouble. I am trying to do a simple `select * from recipes where _id = 1`. I know this row exists because when I run the query `select * from recipes` I get the expected result list. But i dont get any results when I use the `where` clause. If how ever I do a `where` clause on another table in the DB I get the expected results.

Can any one tell me where I have gone wrong?

**Table Create**

```
//Recipe create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + RECIPE_TABLE + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT,"
        + KEY_CODE + " INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_RECIPE_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
```

**Query**

```
    return db.rawQuery("select * from recipes where _id = 1",null);
```

**Putting Result into List**

```
    Cursor cursor = adapter.possibleRecipes();


    //String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_NAME, db.KEY_CODE, db.KEY_ROWID};
    String[] columns = new String[] {adapter.KEY_RECIPE_NAME, adapter.KEY_ID};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.recipe_name, R.id.recipe_code};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row1, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView recipeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.possibleRecipeList);
    recipeList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Comment: I have updated the query above without the \n and \t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, AUTOINCREMENT is written without a space. And when creating a table I would write INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried making the changes you suggested but now when I try run the command it says the table doesnt exist

Comment: Got it working kind of, thanks for the help pointed me in the right direction, will award the bounty when i am allowed

Comment: Thank you! I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

What is a KEY_ID value?

Also, try to replace

```
"select * from recipes where _id = 1"
```

With

```
"select * from recipes where " + KEY_ID + " = 1"
```

Comment: KEY_ID has a value of _id for the column, Thanks for the suggestion but that didnt make a difference. Its like table isnt creating KEY_CODE and KEY_CODE